# Zend pdf origin coordinates

Tags: zend-framework, pdf

I am using zend pdf to draw some elements into my existing pdf file but, i have some issues. Sometimes, the origin coordonate is at the left bottom of the pdf, and sometimes on left top.

How can i manage that?

Can i overwrite my existing pdf file with new coordonate origin?